# Impala KUDU table - howto bulk update

Tags: impala, apache-kudu

I need to performing updates of KUDU table, Is there any option to du update in bulk?

The flow is following:
1 .Fetch 1000 rows
2. Process rows, calculate new value for each row
3. Update KUDU table with new values

Updating row by row with one DB query per row - slow. I am seeking bulk update solution. I found only this "You can update in bulk using the same approaches outlined in Inserting In Bulk." here https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kudu/latest/topics/kudu_impala.html#update_bulk but how to du this? I need example, if it is possible
Thanks